# Rails: Search method breaks PostgreSQL, alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by

I have the following method in my app:

```
def self.tagged_with( string )
  array = string.split(',').map{ |s| s.lstrip }
  joins(:tags).where('tags.name' => array ).group('photos.id')
end
```

This is searching photos, which have many tags through taggings.

This method takes a comma separated list of tags and returns any photos that have associated tags with the given names.

The problem is, it breaks PostgreSQL with the following error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  column "photos.custom_title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
: SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "photos"."id" = "taggings"."photo_id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "tags"."name" IN ('village') AND ("photos".collection_id = 1) GROUP BY photos.id LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0):
```

In another somewhat similar question an answerer suggested that whenever using `.group()` it was necessary to include all columns in the table. This seems insane to me -- what the heck is the point of `.group` if you can only use it by typing up all the fields in your model. That's brittle, and just a bad idea overall.

Can anyone suggest an alternative way to make this method work with PostgreSQL?

Comment: If you want to duplicate mysql's shlocky behavior you want: `select distinct on (photo.id) * ...` Unfortunately, `select distinct  photos.*` did just what the *enemy* wanted you to do ... actually group by all the columns, albeit you got to use a star instead naming all of them. You may not want this either ... but who cares ... data came out so it must be good ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://awesomeful.net/posts/72-postgresql-s-group-by).

One of the suggestions ("Option 2") is to add `select("distinct photos.*")` before your join. I've never done this but it seems worth a try; certainly better than putting every selected field into an aggregate function.

Comment: This saved my day, worked perfectly, and the excellent explanatory article was the icing on the cake. Thank you very much.